# this.find(...) never reaches callback within static method

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, mongoose-plugins

I am working on a module which adds Friendship-based relationships to a Schema.

I'm basically trying to do what [this guy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27335431/call-to-a-static-method-to-a-schema-inside-a-plugin-in-mongoose?rq=1) is trying to do (which, AFAIK, should work--which is discouraging)

Why is `find(...)` in `FriendshipSchema.statics.getFriends` never reaching its callback?

**EDIT** - Please allow me to explain the expected execution flow...

inside `accounts.js`:

1. requires the 'friends-of-friends' module (loads `friends-of-friends/index.js`) which

   1. requires `friends-of-friends/friendship.js` which exports a function that creates `FriendshipSchema`, adds static methods, returns `Friendship` Model.
   2. requires `friends-of-friends/plugin.js` which exports the mongoose plugin that adds static and instance methods to `AccountSchema.
2. uses `FriendsOfFriends.plugin` (see `friends-of-friends/index.js`) to plug-in the functionality from `friends-of-friends/plugin.js`
3. defines `AccountSchema.statics.search` which calls `this.getFriends`.
   Since `this` refers to the `Account` model once it is compiled, and since the plugin added `schema.statics.getFriends`, calling `this.getFriends` within `AccountSchema.statics.search` will call `schema.statics.getFriends` as defined in `friends-of-friends/plugin.js`, which will call `Friendship.getFriends` (defined by `FriendshipSchema.statics.getFriends` in `friends-of-friends/friendship.js`) which calls `this.find(...)` which should translate to Friendship.find(...)`
4. after retrieving an account document, I call `account.search('foo', function (...) {...});`, but as you can see in `FriendshipSchema.statics.getFriends`, the `find` method executes, but its callback is never invoked and the program hangs :(

I don't get any errors, so I know this is a logic problem, but I'm not sure why things are getting hung up where they are...

**EDIT** - see my answer below, I also needed to compile the models before I could call `find` on them.

account.js

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    passportLocalMongoose = require('passport-local-mongoose');

var FriendsOfFriends = require('friends-of-friends')();

// define the AccountSchema
// username, password, etc are added by passportLocalMongoose plugin
var AccountSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    created:        { type: Date,       default:    Date.now                    },
    profile: {
        displayName:    { type: String,     required:   true,       unique : true,  index: true     },
        firstName:      { type: String,     required:   true,       trim: true,     index: true     }, 
        lastName:       { type: String,     required:   true,       trim: true,     index: true     }, 
    }
});

// plugin the FriendsOfFriends plugin to incorporate relationships and privacy
AccountSchema.plugin(FriendsOfFriends.plugin, FriendsOfFriends.options);

AccountSchema.statics.search = function (userId, term, done) {
    debug('search')

    var results = {
            friends: [],
            friendsOfFriends: [],
            nonFriends: []
        },
        self=this;

    this.getFriends(userId, function (err, friends) {

       // never reaches this callback!

    });

};

AccountSchema.methods.search = function (term, done) {
    debug('method:search')
    AccountSchema.statics.search(this._id, term, done);
};

module.exports = mongoose.model('Account', AccountSchema);
```

friends-of-friends/index.js

```
/**
 * @author  Jeff Harris
 * @ignore
 */

var debug = require('debug')('friends-of-friends');
    friendship = require('./friendship'),
    plugin = require('./plugin'),
    privacy = require('./privacy'),
    relationships = require('./relationships'),
    utils = require('techjeffharris-utils');

module.exports = function FriendsOfFriends(options) {

    if (!(this instanceof FriendsOfFriends)) {
      return new FriendsOfFriends(options);
    } 

    var defaults = {
        accountName:    'Account',
        friendshipName: 'Friendship', 
        privacyDefault: privacy.values.NOBODY
    };

    this.options = utils.extend(defaults, options);

    /**
     * The Friendship model
     * @type {Object}
     * @see  [friendship]{@link module:friendship}
     */
    this.friendship = friendship(this.options);

    /**
     * mongoose plugin
     * @type {Function}
     * @see  [plugin]{@link module:plugin}
     */
    this.plugin = plugin;

    debug('this.friendship', this.friendship);

};
```

friends-of-friends/friendship.js

```
var debug = require('debug')('friends-of-friends:friendship'),
    mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    privacy = require('./privacy'),
    relationships = require('./relationships'),
    utils = require('techjeffharris-utils');

module.exports = function friendshipInit(options) {

    var defaults = {
        accountName:    'Account',
        friendshipName: 'Friendship',
        privacyDefault: privacy.values.NOBODY
    };

    options = utils.extend(defaults, options);

    debug('options', options);

    var ObjectId = mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId;

    var FriendshipSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
        requester: { type: ObjectId, ref: options.accountName, required: true, index: true },
        requested: { type: ObjectId, ref: options.accountName, required: true, index: true },
        status: { type: String, default: 'Pending', index: true},
        dateSent: { type: Date, default: Date.now, index: true },
        dateAccepted: { type: Date, required: false, index: true }
    });

    ...

    FriendshipSchema.statics.getFriends = function (accountId, done) {
        debug('getFriends')

        var model = mongoose.model(options.friendshipName, schema),
            friendIds = [];

        var conditions = { 
            '$or': [
                { requester: accountId },
                { requested: accountId }
            ],
            status: 'Accepted'
        };

        debug('conditions', conditions);

        model.find(conditions, function (err, friendships) {
            debug('this callback is never reached!');

            if (err) {
                done(err);
            } else { 
                debug('friendships', friendships);

                friendships.forEach(function (friendship) {
                    debug('friendship', friendship);

                    if (accountId.equals(friendship.requester)) {
                        friendIds.push(friendship.requested);
                    } else {
                        friendIds.push(friendship.requester);
                    }

                });

                debug('friendIds', friendIds);

                done(null, friendIds);
            }

        });

        debug('though the find operation is executed...');
    };

    ...

    return mongoose.model(options.friendshipName, FriendshipSchema);
};
```

friends-of-friends/plugin.js

```
var debug = require('debug')('friends-of-friends:plugin'),
    mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    privacy = require('./privacy'),
    relationships = require('./relationships'),
    utils = require('techjeffharris-utils');

module.exports = function friendshipPlugin (schema, options) {

    var defaults = {
        accountName:    'Account',
        friendshipName: 'Friendship',
        privacyDefault: privacy.values.NOBODY
    };

    options = utils.extend(defaults, options);

    var Friendship = mongoose.model(options.friendshipName);

    ...

    schema.statics.getFriends = function (accountId, done) {
        debug('getFriends')

        var model = mongoose.model(options.accountName, schema);

        var select = '_id created email privacy profile';

        Friendship.getFriends(accountId, function (err, friendIds) {
            if (err) {
                done(err);
            } else {
                model.find({ '_id' : { '$in': friendIds } }, select, done);
            }
        });
    };

    ...

    schema.methods.getFriends = function (done) {
        schema.statics.getFriends(this._id, done);
    };
};
```

Comment: To the person who gave me -1, will you please enlighten me with your reasoning or a suggestion to improve my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was related to which instance of mongoose was being required.

Within my main app, I was requiring mongoose from  `app/node_modules/mongoose` whereas my `friends-of-friends` module--having listed mongoose as a dependency in `package.json`--was requiring mongoose from `app/node_modules/friends-of-friends/node_modules/mongoose`, which created two separate mongoose instances, which made things not work.

I removed mongoose as a dependency, removed the nested `node_modules` folder, and vioala, it works, again :)

should have [RTFM](http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_loading_from_node_modules_folders)

```
app/
|   lib/
|   node_modules/ 
|   |   mongoose/             <-- main app required here
|   |   friends-of-friends/
|   |   |   node_modules/     <-- deleted; mongoose was only dep
|   |   |   |   mongoose/     <-- friends-of-friends module required here
|   server.js
```